# Calculate all four second-order partials derivates and check that f(xy) = f(yx). Variables are restricted to domain where function is defined

Tags: multivariable-calculus

f(x,y) = e^(2xy)

f(xx) = 4e^(2xy)
f(yy) = 4e^(2xy)
f(xy) = 4e^(2xy)
f(xy) = 4e^(2xy)

I think I'm dumb.  Why would these not be the four second-order partial derivatives?  Doesn't e^(anything) stay the same while you take the derivative of the inside?  Why would these not be correct?

Thank you.

Comment: $f_{xx}=(2y)(2y)f(x,y)=4y^2e^{2xy}$; remember $y$ is a *constant* when finding $f_x$.

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe I was making such a simple mistake.  

So for fxy and fyx, when you combine the fx and fy derivates, it be 4xye^(2xy)?

Comment: @David No it is incorrect.  Use the Product Rule. $$f_{xy}=\dfrac{\partial (2y~\mathrm e^{2xy})}{\partial y}=\ldots$$

Comment: By "combine" I thought he meant multiply $f_x$ with $f_y$

Comment: Thank you!  Took me awhile, but I got it!

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't e^(anything) stay the same while you take the derivative of the inside?

Yes, but the chain rule also applies.   Thus when $c$ is constant and $v$ a variable: $$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d~\mathrm e^{cv}}{\mathrm d v}~&=~\dfrac{\mathrm d (cv)}{\mathrm d v}\cdot\mathrm e^{cv}\\[1ex]&=~c\,\mathrm e^{cv}\end{align}$$

Also remember the product rule $$\dfrac{\mathrm d (f(v)\cdot g(v))}{\mathrm d v}=f(v)\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d g(v)}{\mathrm d v}+\dfrac{\mathrm d f(v)}{\mathrm d v}\cdot g(v)$$

This works the same for multivariate derivatives as it does for monovariates.

---

Find the two first derivatives first.$$\begin{split}f_{x}&=\dfrac{\partial\mathrm e^{(2y)x}}{\partial x}\\[1ex]&=2y~\mathrm e^{(2y)x}\end{split}\qquad\begin{split}f_{y}&=\dfrac{\partial\mathrm e^{(2x)y}}{\partial y}\\[1ex]&=2x~\mathrm e^{(2x)y}\end{split}$$

Now you may find the four second derivatives.

$$\ddots$$

---